# Solving the Recurrence relation of $T(n) = 2n + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T(k)$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I want to solve

$$
T(n) = \begin{cases} 2n + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T(k) & n > 1 \\ 1 & n = 1 \end{cases}
$$

but i got stuck at sigma notaion, if $T(n-1)$ its gonna change into $T(n-2)$, $T(n-3)$, but in this problem what does the sigma for?

Comment: \begin{align}
T(2) &= 2\cdot 2 + 2 + T(1)\\
T(3) &= 2\cdot 3 + 3 + (T(1) + T(2))\\
T(4) &= 2\cdot 4 + 4 + (T(1) + T(2) + T(3))\\
&\  \ \vdots
\end{align}

Comment: welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't). In the future you should do the same so that other users have an easier time finding this question. As an aside, do you mean $2n + n + \text{stuff}$? Is there a reason you didn't write it was $3n$? Perhaps you meant $2n + n \cdot \text{stuff}$ instead? I've stayed true to the original image, but I think this needs clarifying.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: @Wang YeFei, are you sure your edit is what OP wanted? I faithfully copied the original linked image (see my comment above, as well as Math1000's example from before my edit)

Comment: Here is the original image -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/V48UU.jpg. To be clear, I think that your edit is probably what OP intended. But I think it's better to wait for them to make an edit like this

Comment: I just changed it to $2n + n$. It's quite hard to view his written note.

Comment: i write it wrong, it should be 2n + 2

Answer (score 0):

Let $s_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n T(k), n \ge 1,s_0 = 0\implies s_n - s_{n-1} = T(n) = 2n +2(s_{n-1} - s_{n-2}), s_1 = 1, s_2 = T(1)+T(2) = 1+6=7\implies s_n-3s_{n-1}+2s_{n-2}=2n, n\ge 3. $. Put again $x_n = s_n - s_{n-1} \implies x_n - 2x_{n-1}=2n, n\ge 2,  x_1 = 1, x_2= s_2 -s _1 = 7-1 = 6 \implies \dfrac{x_n}{2^n} - \dfrac{x_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}} = \dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}, n \ge 2$. Put $y_n = \dfrac{x_n}{2^n}\implies y_n - y_{n-1} = \dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}, n \ge 2, y_1 = \dfrac{1}{2}$. From this telescoping pattern you can solve for $y_n$, then solve for $x_n$, and then solve for $s_n$ using telescoping again, and finally solve for $T_n$. It's long but fun to do rather than using characteristic equation which is uninteresting and cumbersome.

Comment: Compute the very first terms; add $1$ and notice that all can be divided by $?$ and $*$